# How to "Save As" with a unique click?

Tags: html

Please suppose I have many downloadable pictures (in example, one thousand JPG images) in form of hyperlinks, as follows:

http://12.10.11.114/images/00000001.jpg

http://12.10.11.114/images/00000002.jpg

http://12.10.11.114/images/00000003.jpg

.....

http://12.10.11.114/images/00000999.jpg

I would like to download them with a unique "Save As": is it possible?  How can I realize that?

Comment: If you mean that your personally are trying to download these images from a website, try the DownThemAll extension for Firefox.

Comment: I /think/ you mean that you have on your web page 1000 links to 1000 images and you want to let the user select any or all; then download and save them in one go. Is that so? Or am I wrong?

Comment: You're right, the solution was suggested by "oblig" user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various plugins for various browsers that offer "save all links on page" functionality. Example: [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) for Firefox.

If you mean offering a single download of several files, you'd probably want an archive file format similar to how Google Mail offers downloads of all email attachments.